# Stub won't return different return values using repeat

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

The set-up is quite simple:

```
var myMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IInterface>();
myMock.Stub(r => r.GetAll(null))
      .IgnoreArguments();  


myMock.Return(new List<DTO> { dto2 }).Repeat.Once();
myMock.Return(new List<DTO> { dto1, dto2 });
```

dto1 and 2 are 2 predefined objects.

When the method GetAll is called the first time, the list with 2 items is returned! The first definition should be returned first, and then all other calls would return the list with 2 items.

What is happening?

**I've searched for the reason, but found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In RhinoMocks you probably need to record an ordered sequence of expectations:

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IInterface>();
using (mock.GetRepository().Ordered())
{
   mockFoo.Expect(x => x.GetAll(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(result1);
   mockFoo.Expect(x => x.GetAll(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(result2);
}
mock.Replay();

// rest of the test goes here...

mock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

In Moq it would be a bit more elegant with `SetupSequence`:

```
myMock.SetupSequence(x => x.GetAll(It.IsAny<TheArgType>()))
        .Returns(new List<DTO> { dto2 })
        .Returns(new List<DTO> { dto1, dto2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with a nasty workaround:

```
 var callNumber = 1;
 myMock.Stub(r => r.GetAll(null))
       .WhenCalled(m =>
       {
          m.ReturnValue = callNumber != 1 ? new List<DTO> { dto1, dto2 } : new List<DTO> { dto2 };

          callNumber++;
       });
```